# Exchange 2010 Whitespace after Archive move

Tags: exchange-2010, storage, archive

We have multiple Archive Mailbox databases.

I have had to create a new one with 500GB of Data space for the archives and 150GB for the logging files.

The problem I am having is that even after moving 100GB of Archive mailbox data from one database to the new database, the whitespace and the Database disk free has not changed on the previous database. However I know the Archives have moved from checking the users settings in Exchange and also the new database is showing that space has been used.

Is there something else I need to do in order to free up the space from the old database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of two things to free up white space:

1. Create a new database, move everything to it, and delete the old database.
2. Perform an offline defrag of the database.

To perform an offline defrag (Assuming a database named ExchangeDB1 and free space to hold the temporary working database file in `t:\TMP\`

1. Open Exchange shell, and `cd` to the database file location
2. `Dismount-Database ExchangeDB1`
3. `eseutil /d ExchangeDB1.edb /tt:\TMP\temp.edb`
4. `Mount-Database ExchangeDB1`

I usually plan for about 5 minutes per GB for an offline defrag, but that's just a guess and it really depends on too many factors to give a detailed estimate for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
Would I be able to do a defrag or anything without the need of moving everything out and into a new database?